# Pronunciation in the dictionary application?

Tags: android, dictionary, text-to-speech

I'm making a English - Vietnamese dictionary application, please suggest how to pronouce an English word.

I mean, Is there any solution to make: **Input: a word + phonetic -> Output: sound?**

I already thought about Text-to-Speech, but it requires an internet connection so it doesn't work for my Dictionary App.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TTS does not require an internet connection except fist time if tts lib has not been installed in sd card.

```
 TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
 tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
 tts.speak("Hello..I am TTS", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html